# OpenSource scanning software?

Tags: scanning

Can anyone recommend software for scanning documents/images? Preferable opensource / freeware.

Ideally I would like to capture the images and provide some form of indexation if possible, and to save the documents either to a directory or directly into a database (Oracle BLOB for example)

I'm looking for some good alternatives to Kofax or Oracle Document Capture

Thanks

Comment: Best not to store the images in the database as BLOBs, store a path to the file somewhere instead.

Comment: I agree with Lunatik on that one

Comment: The reason for using blobs is for using Oracle CMSDK, if it were a straight php environment I could see the advantages of storing to disk. ;)

Comment: Better use http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for such questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SimpleOCR](http://www.simpleocr.com/)

> **Input Formats**   
> SimpleOCR works with all fully compliant TWAIN
> scanners and also accepts input from
> TIFF files.
>
> **Output Formats**   
> SimpleOCR can save the documents it acquires in text
> formats (TXT and RTF) importable into
> most every program such as Word,
> WordPerfect, HTML editors, and e-mail
> programs, either fully formatted or as
> plain text.  Additionally, it can save
> scanned documents in the industry
> standard TIFF format, a format as
> widely accepted as PDF files.

Answer (score 4):

Try [CuneiForm](http://openocr.org/.) or [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) (currently developed by Google).